# Is STLPort's string implementation using reference counting?

Tags: c++, string, stl, reference-counting, stlport

Is STLPort implemented string via reference counting mechanism?

Comment: @FredO: Because CoW implementations aren't thread safe without excessive performance drops, for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to the source, **no**.](http://gitorious.org/stlport/mainline/blobs/master/stlport/stl/_string.h)